# Logging spring oracle connection details[Hibernate + Hikari + SpringBoot]

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp, tns

I am working oracle DB and experiencing unknown Timeout issue when migrated my application from AWS to GCP. I need to have TNS and SpringOra logs so that the cause could be identified.

I am using Logback-spring.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <include resource="com/sabre/ngp/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <appender name="SOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>[%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%logger] [%-5level] - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="ALL" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa" level="ALL" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SOUT"/>
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ALL" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SOUT"/>
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Why this XML file? You can just specify `logger.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa=ALL` in your `application.properties`. When you get a timeout generally you already get an exception including the point where it goes wrong. When using Spring Boot and Hikari set a min/max size (make sure they are different) and a max time for the query and the connection/read timeouts for proper connection pooling and error reporting.

Comment: @M.Deinum As you can see springframework.orm.jpa is already added. I need TNS and ORA logging

Comment: To debug oracle you need a driver with debug logging enabled and enable the `oracle.jdbc` with `TRACE` or `DEBUG`. Oracle uses `java.util` logging, and Spring Boot replaces that with JUL and bridge, so in theory it should work. But it requires a different driver.